# Добавлять и удалять идентификатор при клике по родителю

Tags: jquery

Не могу понять как добавлять/удалить **id="xxx"** в теги по клику по родителю с помощью jquery

Код:

```
<span id="departure">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selector">
    <span class="selector-left">Отправление</span>
  </a>
</span>

<span id="arrival">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selector">
    <span class="selector-right" id="selector-right-2">Прибытие</span>
  </a>
</span>
```

Задача:

```
$("#departure").click(function()
   {
   удалить у $("#arrival") id="selector-right-2" // <span class="selector-right" id="selector-right-2">Прибытие</span> 
   вставить $("#departure") id="selector-left-2" // <span class="selector-left" id="selector-left-2">Отправление</span>

   });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

UPD: Исправлено

```js
/*$("#departure").click(function() { 
  $(this).attr({id:"selector-left-2"});
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});
$("#arrival").click(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr('id'); 
  console.log($(this).attr('id'))
});*/

$("#departure").click(function() { 
  $('.selector-left').attr({id:"selector-left-2"});
  $('#selector-right-2').removeAttr('id'); 
  console.log($('.selector-left').attr('id'), $('#selector-right-2').attr('id'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="departure">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selector">
    <span class="selector-left">Отправление</span>
  </a>
</span>

<span id="arrival">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="selector">
    <span class="selector-right" id="selector-right-2">Прибытие</span>
  </a>
</span>
```

Comment: В этом случае id=selector-left-2, если я правильно понимаю (я уже так пробовал), присваивается тегу <span id="departure">, а нужно присвоить его <span class="selector-left"> , который внутри  - я вот этот момент не очень понимаю.

Comment: а удалять нужно вообще у другого родителя  id=selector-right-2 , т.е. есть сложности

Comment: Кликаю по "Отправление" и `<span class="selector-left">`  получает атрибут `id=selector-left-2` . Кликаю по "Прибытие" и у  `<span class="selector-right" id="selector-right-2">`  удаляется `id="selector-right-2"` правильно понял?

Comment: кликаю по "Отправление" и `<span class="selector-left">` получает атрибут `id=selector-left-2 ` **И** удаляется у  `<span class="selector-right" id="selector-right-2">`  `id="selector-right-2"`

Comment: кликать по "прибытие" не надо, там я уже разберусь сам по аналогии.

Comment: @hibinyru Сейчас попробуй, если правильно понял должно работать..

Comment: спасибо большое. а не подскажешь, если таких конструкций на странице 2,  а хотелось бы чтобы нажатие срабатывало внутри одной. как заставить чтобы отрабатывало внутри констуркции, т.е. что-то типа `$(this).('.selector-left').attr({id:"selector-left-2"});` (понятно что не работает, но смысл я думаю понятен) и удалить у  `$("#arrival").('#selector-right-2').removeAttr('id'); `

Comment: так. первое сделал. $(this).closest("#departure").find(".selector-left").attr({id:"selector-left-2"});

Comment: а как теперь удалить id у чужого блока?

Comment: Вместо '.selector-left' в этой конструкции `$('.selector-left').attr({id:"selector-left-2"});` Вставляешь имя класса, или id элемента у которого нужно изменить/добавить id. А чтобы удалить вместо #selector-right-2 в этой конструкции `$('#selector-right-2').removeAttr('id'); ` Вставляешь имя класса, или id элемента у которого нужно удалить id.

Comment: СПАСИБО!!! Победил!!!!

Comment: На здоровье! :)